# How to render a template in VueJS to be used on index.html

Tags: vue.js

We have Rails app with Webpacker that serves just the initial HTML file, after which the client will download everything (inc. vue .js and .css) files.

Our problem is that we want to display something initial on the html so the user will feel as the site already loaded. This logic is in the main vuejs component. Is there a way to offline render this so it will be easily be embedded on our index page? instead of having to maintain and re-write this everytime?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like pre-rendering might be a better fit for you than full-on SSR.  Since you're already rolling Webpack, there is a plugin that helps to that end called `prerender-spa-plugin`: https://github.com/chrisvfritz/prerender-spa-plugin

The idea behind this plugin is that, as part of your build process, it prerenders the resulting static HTML of your SPA using Puppeteer (i.e. headless Chrome), and drops it into your static HTML folder. It maintains links to your SPA code so it's still fully functional, it's just fully rendered by the time the user hits it.

What I'd suspect you'd want to try is the following:

1. Add the `prerender-spa-plugin` to your `webpack.config.js`
2. Configure the plugin to prerender your initial route and any additional routes that are truly static
3. Output the resulting files to the folder your Rails app uses to distribute static assets (HTML, CSS, images, etc)

Going the pre-render route is actually technically superior to SSR for truly static routes like a landing page or marketing pages.  You won't need to mess with a complex pre-render setup on your Rails server, you offload content distribution to the static folder (i.e. lesser load on your Rails server), and you still get to use all the benefits of your SPA.

That being said, if you strongly feel like you do need full-blown SSR, the generally "accepted" approach is rolling a Node.js server (https://ssr.vuejs.org/). If you decide to go down this route, I'd keep your SPA assets in their own separate Git repo from your Rails server and manage DevOps appropriately.

Good luck!

Comment: its quite problematic as I see it, as my index.html is served from the server (html.erb) file